# Groups = symmetries?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, lie-groups, symmetry

Tradition in physics tends to match the concept of group with that of "symmetry". Are there good and/or profound reasons to do so?

If one sticks with the intuitive content of "symmetry", this word should be reserved to orthogonal and unitary groups.
Ok, many abstact (Lie) groups have nice representations in unitary groups, but in general none of these representaiions is injective, so the group is not isomorphic to a subgroup a unitary group.

In those cases, isn't it an abuse of language to still refer to the members of such a Lie group as "symmetries"?

And even worse: many people do so not only with Lie groups, but with the general concept of group.

Answer (score 4):

Symmetries are maps from an object to itself which preserve some structure. The identity map is always a symmetry, the composition of two symmetries is a symmetry, and symmetries are generally invertible (either because a non-invertible map would destroy the structure, or because we decree that symmetries need to be bijective).

Therefore, the collection of symmetries of any object naturally forms a group, with the operation of composition.

If you have four identical particles, for example, any permutation of those particles is a symmetry, since the state before the permutation is indistinguishable from the state after. So we say that $S_4$ is the group of symmetries of $4$ identical objects. There's no need to restrict ourselves to unitary and orthogonal groups. Not all symmetries are transformations of inner-product spaces.

Comment: This shows all symmetries are groups and finite groups are subsets of symmetric group, can one view any group as representing some symmetry?

Comment: Every group is the automorphism group of some graph, for example. This is Frucht's theorem (extended to infinite groups by de Groot and Sabidussi).

Comment: Any group can be viewed as a symmetry of a *mathematical* object (itself to start with, but also its group ring, or the vector space it generates). Is each group a symmetry group of some physical system or mathematical object of physical interest, this is more complicated

Comment: So any bijection of a set onto itself could be considered as a "symmetry " ? It seems to me a little bit abusive if one thinks to the intuitive notion of a symmetry isn;t it ?

Comment: It's a symmetry of the naked, unstructured set, yes. I'm not sure "the intuitive notion" is the same for all people, and I'm not sure it's valuable to force the profound concept of symmetry to mimic whatever intuitive notions might be out there.

Comment: Ok so if you take as definition of a symmetry any permutaion that respects some structure (including unstructured set), so yes any group acts faithfully on itself by translation, and so can be considered as a "symmetry group"

Comment: Acting by translations on itself on the right, the group action will preserve the left-torsor structure as well as any topology/differential structure it might have. (It is a little bit better than just the naked set)